# how to send mongodb logs to kafka?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, minikube

i'm setting up a cluster on Minikube, there are 2 component in the cluster, a flask server and mongodb.
my goal is to bridle the logs of mongo and send it to kafka (kafka resides in my localhost).

perhaps i will have to read the logs of mongo from a file, but i don't know where is it.
my mongo deployment is :

`apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: mongo-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pv-claim`

Comment: I think your question has two parts: (1) how can you get logs from a server to Kafka? (2) how is that done when implemented under minikube.

Comment: for (1) something like filebeat works well for streaming logs to Kafka.

Comment: Yeah is true,  the question should be plitted.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the MongoDB logs path in the MongoDB config file which can be found at `/etc/mongod.conf` . By default the logpath is `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` . 
You can use the Kafka [file connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html) to stream the logs from the log file to a Kafka topic.

Comment: great, i need this for stream the log to kafka, but the logs file is stored in the filesystem of minikube, how can i  accesses that file?
anyway thanks a lot

Comment: If you actually want to get the data from the MongoDB cluster to Kafka, you can obviously use the Kafka connector for MongoDB https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/ .

Comment: It is very convenient to use and the documentation is very easy to understand, I thought you were more interested in the logs for some reason :)

Comment: filestream connector "is not recommended for production use". Filebeat or Fluentbit daemonsets would work better.